# Android : Fragment with list-view

Tags: android

The first child in the layout is the listview for the main Activity UI in Navigation Drawer Layout . And I'm trying to display list-view with fragment and navigation drawer layout but list-view is not display in main Activity UI..Can someone help me how to show list.Thanks in advanced.

Here is my code

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The first child in the layout is for the main Activity UI-->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Side navigation drawer UI -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/navList"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:background="#ffeeeeee" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ListView mDrawerList ;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private String mActivityTitle;
    Fragment fragment = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.navList);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();

        addDrawerItems();
        setupDrawer();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        fragment = new YourListFragment();
        if (fragment != null)
        {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    private void addDrawerItems() {
        String[] osArray = {"Android", "iOS", "Windows", "OS X", "Linux"};
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, osArray);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Time for an upgrade!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupDrawer() {
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Navigation!");
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mActivityTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        // Activate the navigation drawer toggle
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Display listview in fragment

```
public class YourListFragment extends Fragment {

    int DR_CAMERA_REQUEST = 99999;
    ListView allPostListView;
    MyListAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArray = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_post_list_fragment, container, false);
        allPostListView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_AllPost);
        adapter = new MyListAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(),R.layout.all_post_row, bitmapArray);
        allPostListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return rootView;
    }

    public  void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        if (requestCode == DR_CAMERA_REQUEST )
        {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            Log.e("photo ", " = " + photo);
            bitmapArray.add(photo);
            //imgProfilePic.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    }
}
```

Adapter class

```
class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    int DR_CAMERA_REQUEST = 99999;
    ArrayList<Bitmap> bmp = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    ProgressBar pBar;int fixedHeight = 220;
    public MyListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId , ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArray) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.bmp = bitmapArray;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return bmp.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View row, ViewGroup parent) {

        final Holder holder;
        if (row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            row = vi.inflate(R.layout.all_post_row, parent, false);
            holder = new Holder();

            holder.horizontalScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) row.findViewById(R.id.hlist);
            holder.lLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.innerlay);
            holder.imgBtn_Camera = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgButton_Camera);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }

        else
        {
            holder = (Holder) row.getTag();
        }

        LayoutInflater mInflater;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View cur_deal = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.horizontalitem, holder.lLinearLayout, false);
        RelativeLayout rLayout = (RelativeLayout) cur_deal.findViewById(R.id.img_layout);
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) cur_deal.findViewById(R.id.image_AllPost);
        pBar = (ProgressBar) cur_deal.findViewById(R.id.pBar_AllPost);

        holder.lLinearLayout.removeAllViews();

        if(bmp.size() > 0)
        {
            int index = bmp.size() -1;
            rLayout.getLayoutParams().height = fixedHeight;
            Bitmap lastbitmap = bmp.get(index);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(lastbitmap);
            pBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.lLinearLayout.addView(cur_deal);
        }

        //OnClickListener for camera button in the List
            holder.imgBtn_Camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    ((Activity)context).startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, DR_CAMERA_REQUEST);
                    Log.e("Camera", " Open");

                }
            });

        return row;
        }

    final class Holder {

        ImageView imgBtn_Camera;
        LinearLayout lLinearLayout;
        HorizontalScrollView horizontalScrollView;
    }

}
```

Here is my all_post_row.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/hlist"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:measureAllChildren="false"

            android:scrollbars="none">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/innerlay"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:orientation="horizontal"

                >

            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonslayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#D8D8D8"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgButton_FoloowUp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="desc"
            android:src="@drawable/follow_up_grey" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgButton_Camera"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="desc"
            android:src="@drawable/camera_grey" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgButton_RecordAudio"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="desc"
            android:src="@drawable/recorder_gray" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is horizontal.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/img_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:paddingLeft="1dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_AllPost"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pBar_AllPost"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Not sure, but try replacing `android:layout_gravity="left|start"` with `android:layout_gravity="start"`.

Comment: If you use Android Studio you can simply start a project as one that has exactly this sort of drawer. It will work and you can compare that code to yours to see what you're doing differently

Comment: do you get some error or you just don't see the listview inside the fragment?

Comment: No , not getting any error , just don't see the list-view  inside the fragment.

Comment: The only problem in your code might be somewhere inside getView() method of adapter rest all seems to be correct.. can you brief us about how your listview structure would be .. i mean what do you do inside getview basically? That would help get a clearer picture of the scenario

Comment: Two buttons are there one is camera button and another is Audio button and display the images on captured camera and add that bitmap dynamically in HorizontalScrollView.

Comment: Can you post your xml code of  `R.layout.all_post_row` & `R.layout.horizontalitem` so that i could try re-create the entire scenario in my machine once i get back home...

Comment: Please see my below post again , I have post xml code of R.layout.all_post_row & R.layout.horizontalitem. Thanks

Comment: Can you please check whether your **bitmapArray** inside **YourListFragment** contains values when passing it to your adapter in the line `adapter = new MyListAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(),R.layout.all_post_row, bitmapArray);`?

Comment: But why not display at least ui means buttons with ListView .

Comment: This is because there is method called `getCount()` inside Adapter class which should return non-zero value for listview to populate anything...in your case since the value of bitmap array is zero..As a result, your `getCount()` method is returning zero(`return bitmap.size()`) resulting into nothing shown [even those static camera image buttons]..

Comment: Just to check my above comment try changing the getCount() method to something like `return 1; // or return 2;` and you will understand what i am talking in my earlier comment

Comment: @p.Id And also it would be great if you  could briefly explain what are you trying to achieve in your case because you are not on correct path in designing your `getView()` method in terms of what you are trying to achieve i guess..

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

to:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```